# Send cookie in header for authentication

Tags: actionscript-3, session-cookies, siteminder

An SWF-Application is embadded in a Website which uses siteminder for SSO.
The user clicks on a link which open a html-file (secured) which include the SWF-file.

Inside the SWF File there are links which redirect the user to another site (same Domain) secured by siteminder.

When the SWF-file is accssed, the user is authenticated and logged in.
As far as I understood this is done by a cookie which needs to be send in the header when accessing a secured site.

Question: Is it possible to "catch" the valid cookie in AS3 and pass it back to the Website if I click on a link inside my SWF-application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser will automatically include the cookie in all subsequent requests to the server (as long as the cookie is defined for the domain and subdomain in question.)

As long as you just redirect the user to another webpage, you shouldn't have to worry about the session cookies for the same reason that you don't have to worry about cookies when adding a simple anchor-tag link in HTML.